# Populating ComboBox in UWP from SQL Database

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to populate data to `ComboBox` in UWP from a SQL Database. I have tried `DataTables` and other methods shown in code. I have two Code Samples, i was trying to get work arounds.

i'm working to the end Result of a `comboBox` in XAML UWP to have the faculty name and it's `FacultyID` binded in backend.
Your assistance will be of help

I have searched online and tried to use `DataTables`, `DataSource`, Databinding and now with the simple logic in code SAMPLE 2.

```
 //Sample 1: This is the logic i'm trying to implement
using (SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(App.ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from faculty", MyConn);
        DataTable allfaculty = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(allfaculty);

        for (int i = 0; i < allfaculty.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmbEditFaculty.Items.Add(allfaculty.Rows[i]["name"]);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

//Sample 2, carries the idea of populating ComboBox in UWP

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(allfaculty);
MyConn.Close();

try
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in allfaculty.Rows)
    {
        //for example 1st column is an int, 2nd is a string:
        int col1 = (int)dr[0];
        string col2 = (string)dr[1];
        cmbEditFaculty.ItemsSource = allfaculty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When binding data to a UWP control it is advisable to use `ObservableCollection<T>` which also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which observes any changes and automatically updates the control when a new item is added or removed.

I would suggest adding a sort of `FacultyItem` class which represents a single item in the list, then have a `ObservableCollection<T>` property like:

```
public ObservableCollection<FacultyItem> Faculties {get;} =
   new ObservableCollection<FacultyItem>();
```

To set the property as the data source, you could either set it from code (not ideal):

```
cmbEditFaculty.ItemsSource = Faculties;
```

Or set it via data binding (much better), for example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Faculties}" />
```

Now when you read data from the database you will first construct `FacultyItem` instances:

```
//read from db, using a data reader, or a data set, anything
FacultyItem[] facultiesFromDb = GetFacultiesFromDb();
```

And then add them to the collection one by one:

```
foreach (var faculty in facultiesFromDb)
{
    Faculties.Add(faculty);
}
```

If you need to clear the list (you want to replace the collection completely), you could first call `Faculties.Clear()`

This is all quite general description of course and I strongly recommend reading some more on MVVM design pattern and data binding - this is nicely documented in Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm).

Comment: Your perspective would definitely work, i ended up using Entity Framework and bound the data using List, very similar approach but they all work

Comment: Great :-) . If your question is resolved, please consider marking it as answer so that it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Zikmund's answer is probably the right way to go at it, but I already had code I wanted to use that came from Asp.Net. This works to the point I can select objects in list and get the value of the selected object when the selection is changed.

in xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="ddlSelectList" Header="Colors" PlaceholderText="Existing Lists" Width="200" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="DdlSelectList_SelectionChanged" >

        </ComboBox>
```

To add list items from a plain old DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = nModel.DataDAL.ListDataDAL.JobListDataTable();

        this.ddlSelectList.DisplayMemberPath = "HashId";          

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ddlSelectList.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = dt.Rows[i]["HashId"].ToString() });
        }
```

To get the value of the selected item on selection changed:

```
 private void DdlSelectList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (ddlSelectList == null) return;
        var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
        var item = (ComboBoxItem)combo.SelectedItem;         
        string test = item.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Converting a DataTable to a List<> and displaying it in the ComboBox is a piece of cake. Getting the value when the index is changed will then throw this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'YourList' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem'

Using the above method, it is just adding the items as ComboBoxItems, and everything starts working.

Again, probably not the preferred way, but it is a way.